# Is it possible to have authentication on keyspaces in Cassandra?

Tags: database, authentication, cassandra, datastax

I have a Cassandra cluster that has two keyspaces: A and B. Is it possible to enable Cassandra authentication on keyspace A only, meaning that keyspace B can be accessed without authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in cassandra. You have ACLs. Here's a really good overview of the functionality: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra

This is the interesting part for you:

```
CREATE ROLE office_admin;
GRANT SELECT ON KEYSPACE office TO office_admin;
GRANT MODIFY ON KEYSPACE office TO office_admin;
```